# How to convert string to JSON payload in Java

Tags: java, android, json, string, ibeacon

I wonder how to convert string to JSON in Java.

I want to convert

```
iBeaconDevice{address='F1:E4:E4:AD:24:50', uniqueId='null', proximityUUID=b9407f30-f5f8-466e-aff9-25556b57fe6d, major=35823, minor=10411, rssi=-56, shuffled=false}
```

to JSON payload like below:

```json
{
  "address": "F1:E4:E4:AD:24:50",
  "uniqueId": "null",
  "proximityUUID": "b9407f30-f5f8-466e-aff9-25556b57fe6d",
  "major": 35823,
  "minor": 10411,
  "rssi": -56,
  "shuffled": "false",
  "timestamp": 1679470296838,
}
```

Comment: Assuming you have the original object, you should serialize that object instead of its `toString()` form. If you only have the above string form, you will need to write a parser that converts it to an object or Map, or directly to some JSON object type, and then serialize that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try to use Gson.

```
val json = Gson().toJson(your_object)
```

or

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(your_object);
```